# Windows Forms Application to ARM64 (IOT)

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, raspberry-pi3, arm64

Is there a way to convert the project to UWP or should I use another approach? I need to deploy a Windows Forms Application written in C# with VS to Windows 10 IOT on a Raspberry Pi 3b. I've seen mention of a converter, but it seems it is used to publish the app to the Windows Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to rewrite the app as a UWP app. The converter you mention (the [desktop bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop)) will allow packaging your Windows Forms app to store deploy to desktop systems but not for IoT.

Windows 10 IoT does not include the UI stack that a WinForms app depends on. This is documented in the [Windows 10 IoT Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/buildingappsforiotcore) (emphasis added for your scenario)

> No legacy Win32 UI support: IoT Core does not contain APIs to create classic (HWND) Windows. Legacy methods such as CreateWindow() and CreateWindowEx() or any other methods that deal with Windows handles (HWNDs) are not available. Subsequently, frameworks that depend on such APIs including MFC, **Windows Forms** and WPF, are not supported on IoT Core

If your UI and underlying logic are separate then you may be able to keep all or most of the logic layer (UWP supports .Net Standard 2.0) and just rewrite the UI using UWP's Xaml stack.